# Unable to pop up InfoWindow on clicking a marker google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, infowindow, marker, google-geocoder

What am I doing wrong?? I am basically trying to pop open an info window, a very simple one, on clicking the markers.. The markers are showing up fine but the markers click event is not being responded..I am pretty sure the InfoWindow code is not in the right spot .. the addresses for correspoding markers are being fed in by jquery for each..

```
var geocoder;
var map;    
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(39.88445,-86.11084);
var myOptions = {
  zoom: 10,
  center: latlng,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
  myOptions);


$('span.Address .ms-rtestate-field').each(function(index) {
    var addy = $(this).text();
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': addy}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map, 
            position: results[0].geometry.location,
            title:addy
        });
        }else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
    });


    // Creating an InfoWindow          
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: 'Hello world'
   });

    // Adding a click event to the marker
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    return function(){
     // Opening the InfoWindow
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
   });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need one instance of the infowindow and then change the content during the onclick event using the `setContent()` method.  Also, you should put the event handler in the geocode callback function to make sure it gets connected when the geocoder completes.

Try this:

```
// Creating an InfoWindow          
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});

$('span.Address .ms-rtestate-field').each(function(index) {
    var addy = $(this).text();
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': addy}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map, 
                position: results[0].geometry.location,
                title:addy
            });

            // Adding a click event to the marker
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                infowindow.setContent("Hello World!");
                infowindow.open(map, this);
            }); 

        }else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: "
                  + status);
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This did it! I am a newbie at both jquery and google Map API. You are my hero of the day!! :)

Comment: Since I am a beginner and always confused about the 'this' keyword, can you explain what 'this' is poniting to ?? The current marker object that just had the onclick event? Also to get my feet more than just wet, I would now like to set the content of the window to the marker address and also put a "get Direction' link that links to the google.com map page?

Comment: the `this` keyword is referring to the object in the current scope. In this example it is the current marker in the loop because you are attaching the listener to that marker.  You could also write the code like this and still be valid:  `infowindow.open(map, marker);` Here is a better explination of `this` : http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html

Comment: inside of the setContent() method you can add html.  You also have the address stored in the marker title property so you can use that to display it in the infowindow.  `infowindow.setContent("Address: " + this.title);`  Adding a directions link is as easy as inserting an `<a>` tag in the content.